# How to initialise long integer variable with Python3

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, syntax

I have a simple question. My code has a line:

```
max_id=-1L
```

This line works with [python-2](/questions/tagged/python-2) but it is not working on [python-3](/questions/tagged/python-3). How can I fix this problem?

Comment: remove the `L`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks, just checked it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x), `int` and `long`s were merged into each other: `int`s have arbitrary size like `long`s in [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x).

You can thus simply **drop the `L` suffix**:

```
max_id=-1
```